# Problem to Sending Multiple data (Data pass to Android from mongodb via node js)

Tags: android, node.js, mongodb

Here the code is well decorated and it's working. But the problem is I want all the login table data. as like all the login user's email and all the login user's name. how can I do this? Which part of the code I should change?

**This is node js part**

```
const app = express()
const mongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient

const url = "mongodb://localhost:27017"

app.use(express.json())

mongoClient.connect(url, (err, db) => {

    if (err) {
        console.log("Error while connecting mongo client")
    } else {

        const myDb = db.db('myDb')
        const collection = myDb.collection('myTable')


        app.post('/login', (req, res) => {

            const query = {
                email: req.body.email, 
                password: req.body.password
            }

            collection.findOne(query, (err, result) => {

                if (result != null) {

                    const objToSend = {
                        name: result.name,
                        email: result.email
                    }

                    res.status(200).send(JSON.stringify(objToSend))

                } else {
                    res.status(404).send()
                }

            })

        })

    }

})

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log("Listening on port 3000...")
})
```

**This is android part 01**

```
public class LoginResult {

    private String name;

    private String email;
}
```

**This is android part 02**

```
public interface RetrofitInterface {

    @POST("/login")
    Call<LoginResult> executeLogin(@Body HashMap<String, String> map);  
}
```

**This is android part 03**

```
public class andojs extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Retrofit retrofit;
    private RetrofitInterface retrofitInterface;   
    private String BASE_URL = "http://10.0.2.2:3000";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_andojs);



        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        retrofitInterface = retrofit.create(RetrofitInterface.class);
        handleLoginDialog();
    }




 private void handleLoginDialog() {

        View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.login_dialog, null);

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        builder.setView(view).show();

        Button loginBtn = view.findViewById(R.id.login);
        final EditText emailEdit = view.findViewById(R.id.emailEdit);
        final EditText passwordEdit = view.findViewById(R.id.passwordEdit);

        loginBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();

                map.put("email", emailEdit.getText().toString());
                map.put("password", passwordEdit.getText().toString());

                Call<LoginResult> call = retrofitInterface.executeLogin(map);

                call.enqueue(new Callback<LoginResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<LoginResult> call, Response<LoginResult> response) {

                        if (response.code() == 200) {

                            LoginResult result = response.body();


                            AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(andojs.this);

                            builder1.setTitle(result.getName());
                            builder1.setMessage(result.getEmail());

                            builder1.show();

                        } else if (response.code() == 404) {
                            Toast.makeText(andojs.this, "Wrong Credentials", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<LoginResult> call, Throwable t) {
                        Toast.makeText(andojs.this, t.getMessage(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });

            }
        });

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below things

```
res.status(200).json({name:result.name,email:result.email});
```

instead of using `res.status.send`

Comment: Thank you @Yassine. Brother can you say how can I store it on this java class. Shouldn't I change the `public class LoginResult ` class and `public interface RetrofitInterface` class??

Comment: I also think this is not the way :(

Comment: No,you dont change its the same structure test it it should work.But i think you're not parsing the json in the client

Comment: It's providing me with the same thing... only one user's email and name or nothing :(